# Constrained optimization with a vector of (many) variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to solve the following problem:

$ArgMax_{\bf x}$ $f({\bf x})$, where ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$ with $x_i\in[0,10],\forall i\in\{1,...,100\}$.

I can do this with

```
ArgMax[{f[x1,...,x100],assumption}, {x1,...,x100}]
```

where

```
assumption = x1\[Element][0,10] && ... && x100\[Element][0,10]
```

but typing those 100 entries seems so unnecessary. Is there a compact way to do this?

Comment: Something along the lines of `xx = Array[x, 100];
ArgMax[Prepend[Thread[0 <= xx <= 10], f @@ xx], xx]` should do...

Comment: That actually helped me out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @henrik-schumacher in the comments (quoted below) helps with this.

> Something along the lines of xx = Array[x, 100]; ArgMax[Prepend[Thread[0 <= xx <= 10], f @@ xx], xx] should do...